# JSF 2 -- Permanent Redirect (301)

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to implement a 301 redirect from within JSF but when I firebug it I always see a 302 being executed. Would someone be able to show me how to alter the method below to accomplish a 301?

```
/**
 * Redirect to specified destination url
 *
 * @param destination
 */
public static void permanentRedirect(String destination) {
    final ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    try {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);

        if (!response.isCommitted()) {
            externalContext.redirect(destination);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.debug("Could not redirect to " + destination);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't invoke `externalContext.redirect(destination)`. It will *override* the status to 302. You should manually [set the `Location` header](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#setResponseHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [complete the response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#responseComplete%28%29).

```
externalContext.setResponseStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
externalContext.setResponseHeader("Location", destination);
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

Comment: AHA! Thanks again. I honestly don't know what Java/JSF would do without you. I hope Oracle sends you a nice big check for Christmas.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that you've received the `ExternalContext#setResponseStatus()` hint :)

Comment: @BalusC i am using this kind of redirect is it 301 ?
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);

res.setHeader("Location", newUrl);

res.flushBuffer();